# Is it possible Fisher information matrix be indefinite?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, fisher-information

I`m using the Newton-Raphson method for obtaining MLE for parameters for maximizing my objective function.
At each iteration, I want to check that is the Hessian matrix negative definite or not and I see the Hessian matrix **is not** negative definite at some iterations. So, I want to use the **Fisher scoring algorithm** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoring_algorithm#Sketch of derivation)
In this situation, the Fisher information matrix is indefinite!! Is it possible? What are the reasons for this? Are the second-order derivatives wrong? Or are values of expectations incorrect?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "Fisher information matrix"?  As [usually defined,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information#Definition) this doesn't depend (in any way) on "iterations" towards a solution: it depends only on the likelihood function at the optimal parameter.

Comment: I can refer you to this link : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoring_algorithm. I mean expected the observed information matrix calculated at obtained parameter value in previous iteration.

Comment: Thanks.  That's a gradient descent algorithm.  Refer to posts about these algorithms for the (many) problems they can have.

Comment: @whuber Thank you.

Comment: You need to be aware of the difference between the Fisher Information  and the Observed Fisher Information,  see for discussion https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154724/why-exactly-is-the-observed-fisher-information-used   and   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/188251/expected-and-observed-fisher-information

Comment: @ kjetil b halvorsen Thank you. I studied your suggestions. please tell me what do we calculate in the **"Fisher Scoring Algorithm"**? <(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoring_algorithm#Fisherscoring)>

Answer (score 4):

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observed_information the observed Fisher information matrix is just the negative Hessian of the log likelihood function. If your log likelihood function is not convex then the hessian will not be positive-definite (and thus indefinite).

This is the case if you are using the "Observed Fisher Information Matrix" from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoring_algorithm. If you are using the canonical notion of the Fisher Information Matrix (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information#Matrix_form) then it must be positive semi-definite.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  At the first iteration in Newton-Raphson method, I see that the observed fisher information matrix (negative Hessian) from (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoring_algorithm ) is positive definite (for maximizing problem) and after the first iteration it becomes indefinite!! In this situation, Is it correct that I say my log likelihood function is not concave? Does it depend on staring values?

Comment: Yes it is correct that your log likelihood function is not concave; if it were concave then it would be everywhere negative semi-definite. A function is concave if it is everywhere negative semi-definite (and convex for everywhere positive semi-definite). This does not depend on the starting value for the algorithm.

Comment: It's worth noting that since your function is not convex, this algorithm will (almost certainly) not find the global minimum; instead I would recommend some sort of stochastic descent algorithm if a local minimum will not suffice for your use-case.

Comment: @ Jspang  Thank you.