# Should the expected observed fisher information matrix be positive definite in Fisher Scoring algorithm?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, fisher-information

I want to use the Fisher Scoring Algorithm in Newton-Raphson method.
[image]

I(theta_m) in above that calculated at each iteration, has to be positive definite? Is it possible this matrix be indefinite?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible Fisher information matrix be indefinite?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/527029/is-it-possible-fisher-information-matrix-be-indefinite)

Comment: Can you please explain how this is different from the question you asked earlier today?