# Observed Fisher Info as an estimator of Expected Info

Tags: maximum-likelihood, asymptotics, fisher-information, point-estimation

When I construct an asymptotic confidence interval for a parameter $\theta$, taken from a sample iid distributed with a generic pdf/pmf, I usually implement the mle $\hat\theta$ instead of $\theta$, thanks to Slutsky's theorem, in order to use known quantities and to actually compute the CI, i.e.
$\theta\in[\hat\theta \pm z_{\alpha/2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{nI_x(\theta)}}]$.

The problem is that since $\theta$ itself is unknown, $I_x(\theta)$ is unknown too. Now, I know I have two alternatives: 1) using the consistency of $\hat\theta$ and Slutsky's theorem as above, or 2) using the Observed Fisher Information, $J_x(\theta)$

My question is: when I am supposed to use one or the other possibility? Are there some differences, besides computational matters, to use one or the other?

Comment: Maybe dups: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154724/why-exactly-is-the-observed-fisher-information-used, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/495033/why-is-the-observed-fisher-information-defined-as-the-hessian-of-the-log-likelih